# c++ runtime error when 2d array assigning another array value

Tags: c++, runtime

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

bool b[200][200];
int a[46];
int test_cases;
int n;
int m;
int first;
int second;

int main()
{
  cin>>test_cases;
  while(test_cases--){

    cin>>n;
    cin>>m;

    for (int i=0;i<2*m;i++){
      cin>>a[i];
    }
    for (int j=0;j<m;j++){
      first=a[2*j];
      second=a[2*j+1];
      b[first][second]=true;

    }

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Hello. Runtime error seems to occur on the last code 'b[first][second]=true;'

I tried couple of changes and i found if i turn 'b[first][second]=true;' into 'b[second][first]=true;'  error doesn't occur, which is simply to change the order of indices.

There is not a possibility of "out of range error" because memory size of b is [200][200] and range of results of a[*] is from 0 to 10.

I can't figure out where the problem is coming from and i need help. Thank you.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to also provide the sample input together with your source code, as it makes reproducing the error easier.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually i have found the error. The range of m was 0 to 45 and that's why i set the memory size of a as 46. But at the first loop, it takes iteration 2*m times and i had to set memory size of a larger than 2m, which is larger than 46.

Answer (score 1):

> There is not a possibility of "out of range error" because memory size of b is [200][200] and range of results of a[*] is from 0 to 10.

The world is littered with buggy code because people made assumptions like this. The *first* thing you should do is *prove* this correct. That's as simple as placing something like:

```
if (first < 0 || first > 199 || second < 0 || second > 199) {
    cerr << "Violation, first = " << first << ", second = " << second << "\n";
    exit(1);
}
```

immediately before your line that sets the `b[][]` element to `true`.

---

As an aside, it would also be prudent to check other array accesses as well. Since we don't have your test data, we have no idea what value will be input for `n` or `m` but, since those values can result in undefined behaviour (by accessing beyond array bounds), they should also be scrutinised.

If you wanted to be *sure* that those didn't cause problems, you could dynamically allocate to the correct size as necessary. For example, once you've gotten `m` from the user:

```
int *a = new int[m*2];
// Use it as you wish, elements <0..m*2-1> inclusive.
delete [] a;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply :). You are exactly right and the problem was from memory size of a. m is from 0 to 45 and that's why i set the memory size of a as 46. But it had to be larger than 2m like your answer. Thank you again.